# How to iterate through array using nested while loops in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In my code below it seems that the i variable in the 2nd while loop is not incrementing within the 2nd while loop, but it is incrementing in the first while loop. So i is always equal to zero in the 2nd while loop, however I need it to increment +1 each pass.

Here is my code:

```
# Code required to read in the values of k,n and candies.
n = gets.to_i
k = gets.to_i
candy = Array.new(n)
for i in 0..n-1
  candy[i] = gets.to_i
end

#create loop to calculate max-min and compare to lowest max-min value     calculated thus far.
arr = []
i = 0
candy = candy.sort
ans = nil

#iterate through candy array to create n minus k sub-arrays of size k
while i < n-k
  m = 0

  #create sub-array of size k
  while m < k
    arr << candy[i + m].to_i
    m += 1
  end

  #find the difference between the max and the min value in the sub-array
  arrcheck = (arr[k-1]) - (arr[0])
  i += 1

  #if ans is nil set the ans variable to arrcheck, else if arrcheck is less than the ans set ans to arrcheck
  if ans == nil
    ans = arrcheck
  elsif arrcheck < ans
    ans = arrcheck
  end

end

### Compute answer from k, n, candies
puts ans
```

Since the i in the 2nd loop is not incrementing it is just checking the same sub-array n minus k times without advancing through the entire candy array.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i is the same inside the inner loop because you're only incrementing it in the outer loop. Aside from that - what is the problem you're trying to solve? What is it you want to accomplish with your nested loops? Also, providing example input and expected output would be tremendously helpful.

Comment: Two minor points: you don't need the parentheses in `arrcheck = (arr[k-1]) - (arr[0])`; and the last `if..end` can be written: ` (ans = arrcheck) if ans.nil? || arrcheck < ans`.

Comment: Please consider selecting the one and only answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two mistakes in your code:

1. `while i < n - k` should be `while i <= n - k`
2. `arr = []` must be moved into the `while` loop

Fixed code:

```
while i <= n - k
  m = 0
  arr = []
  # ...
```

Although your code works with the above fix, it's not very idiomatic. I'd write something like:

```
print 'number of candies: '
n = gets.to_i

print 'sub-array size: '
k = gets.to_i

candies = []
(1..n).each do |i|
  print "candy #{i}: "
  candies << gets.to_i
end

puts candies.sort.each_cons(k).map { |a| a.last - a.first }.min
```

Let's examine the last line:

```
candies = [1, 7, 10, 2]
k = 2

candies                          #=> [1, 7, 10, 2]
  .sort                          #=> [1, 2, 7, 10]
  .each_cons(k)                  #=> [[1, 2], [2, 7], [7, 10]]
  .map { |a| a.last - a.first }  #=> [1, 5, 3]
  .min                           #=> 1
```

Comment: I like the expository technique you used for "Let's examine the last line."

Comment: What's your opinion on writing: `candies = Array.new(n) { |i| print "candy #{i+1}: "; gets.to_i }`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I wanted to show that Ruby arrays grow dynamically and that there's usually no need to create a fixed sized array up-front.

Comment: On the other hand - why not. `candies = n.times.map { |i| ... }` would work, too.